# Handling References Locations across Users in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering how people handle dealing with references across multiple users across multiple computers.  We have a small dev shop with only a few developers.  We have an issue where reference locations/paths/web.config files get messed up each time a user gets the latest (we use TFS for source control) because the references are located in slightly different paths:  c:\Dave\CommonBin versus c:\Joe\CommonBin .  How do others handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you actually doing development? Local boxes or on a shared box? If local boxes, there is no reason to have c:\Dave and c:\Joe ever show up. If you are on a shared box, you should examine if the methodology is correct, as shared environments == messy.

My methodology is to keep paths the same, relatively speaking. This means everyone uses the same structure, even if the root is not the same (i.e. absolute paths may be different, but the relative path from the .sln file is the same). This allows people to work under the VS 2010 project directory or under another folder (I use c:\projects).

For web work, you can apply this methodology and use the built in web server, but I find using IIS is a better option, as you get rid of some other issues that crop up when using the built in server. This means every developer has to set up IIS directories (not quite true, as Windows 7 with IIS will help your devs out), but either way this is not a huge step and it gets rid of tons of headaches.

If you get consistent, then you end up with conformity amongst the systems and avoid a lot of the issues you are now experiencing. To get there from here, you will have to temporarily bite the bullet and fix things.

Comment: We do have some decent uniformity but we sometimes have to share dev boxes which is why there is Joe/Dave directory in there.

Answer (score 0):

Using a consistent path structure among all devs should help. As far as third party libraries go, it is a good idea to check them in with the project itself. That way you can grab the latest code and build. In my experience, TFS doesn't do well with binary check ins, and because of the integration with visual studio, unless you add solution items and include the libraries there, updating them to new versions can be a pain. You can manage them outside of the solution using the Source Control tools if you don't mind leaving solution explorer for a little bit to manage dependencies.

With web.config files, I tend to check in a web.config.template file, and all changes go there. Then developers can edit the web.config all they want for their local environment and not mess up anyone else. But you do have to remember to ensure changes make it to the template file. Not a perfect scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Project References are included using a relative path.  So it doesn't matter if developers have different project trees as long as long as the relative path to the files are the same.

It sounds like you just need to move the CommonBin directory in to the project tree and it should work.

Comment: How do you include them using a relative path?  When you "Add Reference" it puts the absolute path in for the file?

Comment: Visual Studio uses relative paths automatically.  You should see that if you look at the .csproj file with an editor.